# How to modify text file so that it can be loaded into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, text

I have over a 100 columns in my table and some can be null. I want to input from a txt file. So, some rows may not have all 100 odd entries. 
For example, a line in my text file might have around 50 entries separated by a 'tab' but how do i specify which columns these 50 entries have to be made out of the 100+ columns?
I've read about
    LOAD DATA INFILE but i'm still confused about my problem. Any help is appreciated.

suppose the text file is: 
 Toby, LA 
 Carl, 246 
 and i want the resultant table to be:
 Toby NULL LA 
 Carl 246 NULL 
 How do i do this?

Comment: How do *you* know which columns to specify?

Comment: @eggyal i will be preparing my text file using java. Assume that i will know which columns. I want to know how i specify them and where.

Comment: In that case, why go via a text file and not directly connect to MySQL from Java?

Comment: There are about 7k rows and it takes too much time in java. If i dump all my data in a text file and then into the db in one insert it would be a lot faster.

Comment: To write a file to disk, then read that file from disk and parse its contents is almost certainly slower than a *correctly coded* insertion through Java.  If your attempt to insert through Java is too slow, then I suspect something in your code can be improved.  This sounds like a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: The problem is not about how slow the java insert is. Its that there are too many. And I am assuming that one Insert statement + File handling would be faster than 7k Insert statements.

Comment: What do you mean by "*too many*"?  What limit have you hit?  Moreover, a schema that has 100 sparsely populated columns does not sound particularly relational.  You probably should restructure the schema; perhaps the [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) would help?

Answer (score 0):

With this instruction:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This is the route of your txt:

```
'/tmp/test.txt'
```

You dump the txt on the table named test.

Your txt should have this structure:

```
Toby, 245, LA
Carl, 246, CA
```

For a result like:

```
Toby NULL LA 
Carl 246 NULL
```

The txt should be like:

```
Toby, NULL, LA 
Carl, 246 , NULL
```

Thats because FIELD SCAPED BY Its not specified.

**From Mysql documentation:**

Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES options in use:

For the default FIELDS and LINES values, NULL is written as a field value of \N for output, and a field value of \N is read as NULL for input (assuming that the ESCAPED BY character is “\”).

If FIELDS ENCLOSED BY is not empty, a field containing the literal word NULL as its value is read as a NULL value. This differs from the word NULL enclosed within FIELDS ENCLOSED BY characters, which is read as the string 'NULL'.

If FIELDS ESCAPED BY is empty, NULL is written as the word NULL.
3 fields separated by ',' whit end line \n.....you table test should have the same structure

Comment: I've edited the question to make my point clearer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The text file needs to be organized such that it has a consistent column set. If you have 50 tab-delimited values in one line and then 100 tab-delimited values in the next line then you'll never be able to load the data cleanly into MySQL.

Missing values still need to be accounted for in the text file, using empty string, NULL, etc to signify the missing value.

If you have some existing data in your table that includes NULL values then you can dump a subset of that data to disk in order to get an example of the proper way to format missing values in a tab-delimited file:

```
select *
into outfile '/tmp/test.tsv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
from your_table
limit 1000
```